# How do I display a JSON object using HTML when I am getting the object returned to HTML?

Tags: html, json, glassfish

I am getting the JSON object back TO the HTML request (I am using GlassFish on localhost just to demo). I am not, however, able to display any of my JSON objects. (I am a rookie when it comes to HTML.)

Here is my attempt at HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title>Dss</title>

        <script>
          function onSubmit() {
            alert(document.getElementById('text').value);

            $.ajax({
              url: 'rest/dss/acceptInput',
              type: 'GET',
              dataType: 'jsonP',
              data: {'UserInput': document.getElementById('text').value },
              statusCode: {
                200: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                    $.each( data.items, function(item ) {
                      alert(item.Type);
                      $( "<p>" ).attr( "value", item.Type ).appendTo( "#Test" );
                    });
                },
                404: function() {
                  alert("Page NOT found");
                }
              },
              done: function(data) {


                alert("NOPE" + data);
                $.each( data.items, function(item ) {
                  alert(item.Type);
                  $( "<p>" ).attr( "value", item.Type ).appendTo( "#Test" );
                });
              }
            });

            alert("at the end");
          };
        </script>
    </head>

    <body style="background-color:black;">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/97.png" alt="DSS_Thumbnail" style="display: inline;width:120px;height:120px;">
        <h1 style="display: inline;color:rgb(241,85,50)">Search for details:</h1>
        <br>
        <input id="text" type="text" name="UserInput" value="Enter search criteria">
        <br>
        <button id="submit" onclick="onSubmit()" type='button'>Submit</button>
        <br><br>
        <div id="Test"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I run this in the Chrome browser, and the alerts show me the object Object returns within the status code 200. I am not sure HOW to display this information... I thought I had it, but I have tried for a few hours.
After running the HTML I receive these acknowledgements:

Initial acknowledgement of input:

[image: Initial acknowledgement of input]

Acknowledgement of finish:

[image: Acknowledgement of finish]

Displaying the object after status code 200 received:

[image: Displaying the object after status code 200 received]

I understand that it is asynchronous which is why I would get them out of order, but what do I do with said object Object?

What do i have to add to the HTML file to display the JSON to the current page? (Or even populate a new page with the information on it?)

Comment: Is your `url` path correct? There should be a `.json` file there, or ensure this URL really has API JSONP data. Could you provide us with an example of what you see when you visit that page, localhost/rest/dss/accpetInput?

Comment: absolutely, if i utilize html forms i am redirected to a page with the json array displayed... i just dont want to be re directed. ill load pics of what i am getting

Comment: Instead of alert(item.Type); try alert(item);